# Batch add string into filename before suffix

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename

I'm working on a Windows batch file and I need to change some name of files in current direcotry.

I have these files:

```
ABC_Something.xls
ABC_Something_one.xls
ABC_Something_one_two.xls
ABC_Everything.xls
```

and I need to add string "**_old**" before suffix like this

```
ABC_Something_old.xls
ABC_Something_one_old.xls
ABC_Something_one_two_old.xls
ABC_Everything.xls
```

The last one i need to leave without changes. How to do it? I'm tried to find some solution, but without effects. Thank you.

Comment: What sort order determines the "last" file?  This will get you started at least. `for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /a-d /b') do echo %%~nA_old%%~xA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
attrib +h "ABC_Everything.xls"
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a-d abc_*.xls') do rename %%a %%~na_old%%~xa
attrib -h "ABC_Everything.xls"
```

Comment: I added commands with `ATTRIB` to stop the last file being renamed.

Comment: No worries Endoro.  I suspect the OP wants the 'last' file selected by script but they need to specify if it is last by alphabet or date or whatever.